# Calling Ansible group_vars, host_vars with the same variable key name

Tags: ansible

I've inventory structure like below,

```
[devgroup]
server001
server002
```

what we are trying to do here is to validate mount points on these hosts, there are some common mounts points between these above two servers. Now we've decided to use  group_vars and host_vars to meet the requirement.

```
group_vars/devgroup.yml
host_vars/server001.yml
        /server002.yml
```

```
devgroup.yml has below variables

mounts:
    /a
    /b
server001.yml has
mounts:
    /d
    /e
server002.yml has
mounts:
    /s
    /t
```

So, in above /a /b are in both servers, where as each one has separate unique mount points.
So, now in my playbook how can I get all the variables? as per standards group_vars will overwrite by host_vars if it has same variable(**mounts**) key name. Appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"In my playbook how can I get all the variables?"*

A: Quoting from Ansible configuration settings [DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour):

> By default Ansible will override variables in specific precedence orders, as described in [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) ... Some users prefer that variables that are hashes (aka ‘dictionaries’ in Python terms) are merged. This setting is called ‘merge’. This is not the default behavior and it does not affect variables whose values are scalars (integers, strings) or arrays. We generally recommend not using this setting ...

The variables in the question are not dictionaries and can't be merged.

Instead, let's create dictionaries that might be used to mount filesystems. For example

```
shell> cat group_vars/devgroup.yml
mounts:
    a:
      dev: sda1
      mnt: /a
    b:
      dev: sda2
      mnt: /b
shell> cat host_vars/server001.yml
mounts:
    d:
      dev: sda3
      mnt: /d
    e:
      dev: sda4
      mnt: /e
shell> cat host_vars/server002.yml
mounts:
    s:
      dev: sda5
      mnt: /s
    t:
      dev: sda6
      mnt: /t
```

The playbook

```
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: devgroup
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: mounts
```

by default overrides *group_vars* by *host_vars* and gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
[...]
ok: [server001] => {
    "mounts": {
        "d": {
            "dev": "sda3", 
            "mnt": "/d"
        }, 
        "e": {
            "dev": "sda4", 
            "mnt": "/e"
        }
    }
}
ok: [server002] => {
    "mounts": {
        "s": {
            "dev": "sda5", 
            "mnt": "/s"
        }, 
        "t": {
            "dev": "sda6", 
            "mnt": "/t"
        }
    }
}
```

But with `ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge` the same playbook gives the dictionaries merged

```
shell> export ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 
[...]
ok: [server001] => {
    "mounts": {
        "a": {
            "dev": "sda1", 
            "mnt": "/a"
        }, 
        "b": {
            "dev": "sda2", 
            "mnt": "/b"
        }, 
        "d": {
            "dev": "sda3", 
            "mnt": "/d"
        }, 
        "e": {
            "dev": "sda4", 
            "mnt": "/e"
        }
    }
}
ok: [server002] => {
    "mounts": {
        "a": {
            "dev": "sda1", 
            "mnt": "/a"
        }, 
        "b": {
            "dev": "sda2", 
            "mnt": "/b"
        }, 
        "s": {
            "dev": "sda5", 
            "mnt": "/s"
        }, 
        "t": {
            "dev": "sda6", 
            "mnt": "/t"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, `ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge` does the magic